# Passing argument to react-apollo-hooks useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

How can I pass an argument to useQuery when using react-apollo-hook?

This does not work:

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_DATA,
{ variables: { id: 'testId' }});
```

And the query itself:

```
export const GET_DATA = gql`
{ query ($id: String) {
  document(id: $uid) {
    uid
  }  
 }
}
`;
```

Comment: What is the error? Please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: You can see the actual response from your server in the network tab of your browser's dev tools. If your query is not valid, this will show the validation errors, which will help you troubleshoot your issue. You can search SO for the same error messages, but if you need to open a new question, you should include these errors in your question to help both answerers and future searchers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is not valid because 1) it's wrapped in an extraneous pair of curly brackets and 2) you reference a variable named `uid`, while the variable you defined is actually called `id`. Corrected, this query would look like:

```
query ($id: String) {
  document(id: $id) {
    uid
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, I don't know what your actual schema is so this query could still be invalid if any of the fields or arguments do not exist or are of the wrong type.